Concentric metal spheres and electric potential
Suppose we have three concentric metal spheres such that only the middle one carries a charge $q$, the inner and outer spheres are uncharged. To me it seems that this would induce a charge on the other two metal spheres which is of course proportional to $q$ but will change in sign.
Now apparently the inner and outer spheres acquire a charge which is opposite in sign to each other. This doesn't really make sense to me as I would think that the charge these spheres would get would be both opposite the charge of the middle sphere.
Moreover, when computing the electric field, I would expect the field to essentially look like a point particle throughout the entire space. However, this is apparently not the case as the charges on the inner and outer spheres now also have to be considered.

The electric field inside a spherical charge distribution is zero, so you may want to rethink your assumption that a charge is induced on the inner sphere.

the innermost charged conductor will induce dipoles on the conductor infront of it and which further would induce dipoles on the outermost conductor with the positive charges on the outer surface, the charge however will remain $q$ and the electric field would be as if the charge were concentrated at its centre i.e.
$\vec{E}$ $= \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{q}{r^{2}}$
here is an image explaining it:


this is what i would think also! so in the region in between the middle and outer sphere the electric field will simply be that of a point particle no?

taking the plates to be infinitely thin the electric field throughout all the space occupied by the whole body would be $\vec{0}$ [note $\rightarrow$ i said the plates are infinitely thin]

however the whole body would behave as a point charge for any charge outside the body

i think that's only true inside the middle sphere: between the middle and the outer sphere you the enclosed charge is simply Q, so by Gauss law you get the usual electric field no?

no inside this whole massive conductor there is no enclosed charge, the net charge inside is zero the charge $q$ is only at the surface of the outer sphere
